# scala get path for current module, not of the calling module

Tags: scala

In an intelliJ project, "otherModule" is imported.

The "Main method" in one module, calls "some method" located in "otherModule"

"otherModule" contains resources, for which the path needs to be obtained by the calling module.

What code can be used to get the path to "otherModule", instead of returning the path of the calling module?

eg, if "otherModule" contains code:
var thisModulePath = getClass.getResource("/").getPath

it actually returns the path of the calling module.

Comment: Use `getResources`, as in get a list. You will have different class path in build tool, uber JAR and dockerized app, so it's best to not make your code dependent on how it was organized into folders/JARs.

Comment: Do you really need path to the resources? Otherwise `getResourceAsStream` might be better fitted so that you don't have to care about paths. As said above, depending on how your code runs, path could be very different thus depending on what you do with the path it could not be portable code.

Comment: Surely getResources or getResourceAsStream will only find resources in the originating module? Not relating to resources present in a called module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the JVM, resources are loaded by a class loader. Which class loader that is is determined by the `Class` instance you use.

For example:

```scala
// use the class loader which loaded the current class
getClass.getResourceAsStream("/resource.txt")

// use the class loader which loaded the class ClassInOtherModule
classOf[ClassInOtherModule].getResourceAsStream("/resource.txt")
```

Each class loader can find its own set of resources. However, in practice standalone programs (so not Spark, nor Application containers) use a single class loader for everything so most of the time it doesn't matter much.

'Finding the path of a module' is not really a thing. Modules are compile-time concepts that mostly do not translate to run-time.